# Short Video Transcription

Tags: translation

I'm studying English. I'm trying to transcribe this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybolCCA96zM. 
For now I think that the reporter in the video says this:

> "We talk about kiss cam fight right here. Look at this one: Celtics vs. Chicago Bulls. Can be better without cell phone discuss with smooch her girlfriend?"

Could someone please help me with the transcription?

Comment: well, talk about a kiss cam fail right here, look at this, one Celtics fan in Chicago can't be bothered to put down his cellphone to smooch his girlfriend

Comment: thanks @Tetsujin for the first part traduction. Anyelse could me help with the second part please...

Comment: I believe @Tetsujin covered the whole utterance, i.e., both parts.

Comment: @CarSmack No, he doesn't covered the whole utterance. He only done the translation until the second 8 of the video.

Comment: @juaninf You only asked about that part, not a transcript of the entire video.  People are, by and large, happy to help with this sort of thing to aid learning, but not to just do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full transcription of what the reporter says in the video clip:

"Well, talk about a Kiss Cam fail right here. Look at this. One Celtics fan in Chicago can't be bothered to put down his cellphone to smooch his girlfriend. Well, he gets himself into a fight with the entire stadium watching on the Jumbotron. Well, lucky for him, Benny—that's the Chicago Bulls' mascot—stepped in to save the day, as Benny carries off the girl and maybe gets a smooch. And those are your headlines. Good move, Chicago!"